# Grails 3.x - Forked Execution

Tags: grails, gradle, grails3

i am Migrating a project from grails 2.4 to grails 3.3

in grails 2.4 we have the following forked execution configuration:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
   test: [maxMemory: 4096, minMemory: 1024, debug: false, maxPerm: 16384, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 16384, minMemory: 1024, debug: false, maxPerm: 16384, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 16384, minMemory: 1024, debug: false, maxPerm: 16384, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 16384, minMemory: 1024, debug: false, maxPerm: 16384]
]
```

as described in the grails 2.3 [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.4/guide/commandLine.html):

5.2 Forked Execution

> Forked Execution Since Grails 2.3, the run-app, run-war, test-app and
>   console commands are now executed in a forked JVM in order to isolate
>   the build classpath from the runtime classpath.
>
> Forked execution is configured via the
>   grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file.

however, i couldn't find any documentation on where is the forked execution configuration in grails 3.x

where can i find the documentation on forked execution in grails 3.x?

and where should i move the configuration to?

Comment: Just curious, did you ever find the solution for this?

Comment: I think I got it sorted. I assume this isn't necessary anymore since the switch to gradle. And to configure jvm args we should just use the relevant build block in the build.gradle file to set jvmArgs. That's what seems to be working for me at least.